# How to change checkbox styling React Material-Table Filtering

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

how to edit style for checkbox in filtering?

For example, I want to change the width and height of the checkbox pop up on Birth Place field, how can I do that?

[image: material table]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the withStyles higher order component. Read about it in the official material ui documentation.